# Why is 18 = 4 + 6? Find the general rule

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

I have these kinds of expressions:

- **Correct expressions (true and valid)**
  $$\begin{align}
  3 &= 3\hbox{ (it's obvious, isn't it?)}\\
  4 &= 1 + 3\\
  8 &= 5\\
  9 &= 1 + 5\\
  12 &= 1 + 3 + 5\\
  18 &= 4 + 6
  \end{align}$$
- **True but not valid expressions**
  $$\begin{align}
  3 &= 1 + 2\\
  10 &= 4 + 4\\
  12 &= 5 + 3 + 1\\
  14 &= 1 + 4 + 5
  \end{align}$$
- **Incorrect expressions (false and invalid)**
  $$\begin{align}
  10 &= 4 + 6\\
  11 &= 5 + 6
  \end{align}$$

For each non-negative integer in the left side, there is a unique expression on the right side.

Can you tell what is the general rule? 
I think it is an easy one for you, guys, but feel free to ask for specific values if you need them.

Comment: What is the difference between true and valid expressions?  How can an expression be true, yet not valid?

Comment: A valid expression is written following an specific rule, and a true expression means that both sides have the same value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are the Fibonacci representations of the integers. Valid expressions contain no consecutive or repeated numbers, and are in increasing order.

$3=3=F_3\\
4=1+3=F_1+F_3\\
8=8=F_5\\
9=1+8=F_1+F_5\\
12=1+3+8=F_1+F_3+F_5\\
18=5+13=F_4+F_6$

---

$10=5+5=F_4+F_4$, but it should be written as $2+8=F_2+F_5$ instead.
$14=1+5+8=F_1+F_4+F_5$, but it should be written as $1+13=F_1+F_6$ instead.

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Aren't there two 1 at the begining of the Fibonacci

Comment: @Cryol The first one is sometimes counted as $F_0$.

Comment: Okay then it makes sense. The Fibonacci was the first Thing i looked at :)

Comment: This is based on the Zeckendorf's theorem

Comment: @f'' The Fibonacci sequence starts with [0 1]. Although I suppose that depends on which source you look at, never mind.